# Azure Synapse Studio error: External table 'dbo' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process

Tags: configuration, azure-synapse

I am having the error **'External table 'dbo' is not accessible because location does not exist or it is used by another process.'**

This happens for example when I am trying to run this simple script:

```
SELECT TOP (100) [prlName]
,[FK_prlNpdidLicence]
,[FK_cmpNpdidCompany]
,[cmpLicenseeLongName_DW]
,[prlLicenseeInterest]
 FROM [dbo].[Fac_LicenceShare]
```

The database exists for sure and this error occurs with my user. My colleague who setup the service can run the query successfully.

It must be an issue with the authorizations granted to my user but we do not have a clue what it can be.

Any hints?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the cases provided in the file path of the CSV.
2. Check for any spaces in the CSV file name. No spaces should be used.